# Extra Space Between Slick Slider Dots and Other Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I am using slick slider. The slider is taking extra white space under the slider. When I checked with the Chrome Dev Tools, I found that it is because of the dots of slick slider. I have added custom styles to the dots. Don't understand why I am facing the issue! Here is my Codepen link https://codepen.io/nemo011/pen/aMRJZK

```
<section class="slider">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1680x720">
        <h2>text 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1680x720">
        <h2>text 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1680x720">
        <h2>Lets see</h2>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="donate">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Help Us to Make a Change</h3>
        <div class="btn-dark">Donate</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS Styles

```
 h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-80%, -80%);
    color: white;
    font-size: 46px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.slide {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide img{
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100vw;
}

.slick-dots {
    top: 90%;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.slick-dots li{
    margin: 0 0.25rem;
}

.slick-dots li button {
    display: block;
    width: 0.5rem;
    height: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0;

    border: none;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: white!important;

    text-indent: -9999px;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover{
    background-color: #2f638b!important;
}
.slick-dots li.slick-active button{
    border: 3px solid white!important;
    background-color: transparent!important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .slick-dots {
        top: 90%;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .slick-dots {
        top: 85%;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    .slick-dots {
        top: 70%;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
}

/* Donate Bar Section #donate */
#donate {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #2f638b;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.slider').slick({
                autoplay: true,
                infinite: true,
                //              centerMode: true,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                //              centerPadding: '220px',
                dots: true,
                dotsClass: 'slick-dots',
                fade: true,

            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are styles to 3 elements that are causing the gap.

1. The `<h3>` in `<section id="donate">` has a `margin-top`
2. The `<section class="slider">` has a `margin-bottom`
3. The `<ul class="slick-dots">` has both `bottom` and `top` defined.

These styles are being applied from an external css file being loaded called `slick-theme.css`

Hence, paste the following at the end of your stylesheet.

```
section#donate h3{
  margin-top: 0;
}

ul.slick-dots{
  bottom: 0;
}

section.slick-dotted.slick-slider{
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

And modify the `margin-bottom` of `section.slick-dotted.slick-slider` to obtain the space as per required.

Comment: Solved the issue. Thank you for breaking every part and help me to understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

Modified a bit of your `.slick-dots` style:

```
.slick-dots {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

---

This giving extra white space under the slider:

```
.slick-dotted.slick-slider {
    margin-bottom: 30px; /* Should be removed */ 
}
```

Also the `h3` tag gives `margin-top` value in general, so you can get rid of it by:

```
.container h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved the issue.